# move the navigation bar down to the middle of the page

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I am using Wordpress and have a particular requirement to move the navigation bar and logo down to the middle of the page. Struggling a bit. Obviously most themes will not allow this and Headway it seems will not let me do it either.

Trying to achieve something along these lines: http://www.drewpritchard.co.uk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply add position:fixed; to the div which holds the logo and the menu. This will also make sure that it stays in the middle when you scroll or change the screensize.

The recommended way to do this is to place the code in your style-sheet. You can also put in in your header.php file but then you have got to make sure that you place it within the head elements and put style around it, so:

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #logo-menu-container{
      position:fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      width:200em;
      height:50em;
      margin-top: -25em; 
      margin-left: -100em;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Note that there is an "edit" button below each post, which allows you to add additional information to it; in future, use this rather than posting additional answers. In this instance, I've already combined the two answers, and deleted the other one.